# Meaning of 'Assertive of authority'

Tags: phrase-meaning

While searching for the meaning of the word 'officious' Google gave me this explanation:

> assertive of authority in a domineering way, especially with regard to trivial matters.

I am interested in the meaning of the phrase 'assertive of authority'. My gut tells me it means that one "tends to assert authority", correct me if I'm wrong. But it doesn't feel natural at least in my understanding of English. I would have thought that in conveying the meaning of someone "tending to be a certain person" you would say ***asserting** of authority* instead of ***assertive** of authority*. Can anyone explain such phrasing to me and maybe provide some similar examples where *someone is ***something of something***?

Comment: *shaking head* Why didn't you go look at an online dictionary?

Comment: @FeliniusRex I did, but I don't know exactly how to translate. Check my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @FeliniusRex to rephrase. Can you explain what does it mean to be **assertive** of something?

Comment: Ok, I thought you just searched Google randomly; I understand. I can't improve on Colin Fine's answer and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Asserting authority* would refer to how somebody is being or acting at a particular time.

*Assertive of authority* is describing a person or behaviour timelessly.

The difference is quite subtle, and I'm sure that in some contexts either would do; but for a definition it makes sense to use the timeless version.

The *of* is needed because that's what the adjective *assertive* requires. You would not normally use it with *asserting*, because the verb *assert* can take a direct object: adjectives cannot.

Comment: The definition of assertive is 'having or showing a confident and forceful personality'. I don't know how to translate this exactly. 'Confident of authority'? What does that mean?

Comment: It's not _confident of authority_, @MichaelMunta, it's _confidently or forcefully **showing** one's authority_  (or assumed authority). It's about behaviour, not inner state.

Comment: By the way, do you know of any other phrases that are formed in such a way?

Comment: In what way, @MichaelMunta?

Comment: A phrase formed like 'assertive of authority'. Saying someone is '-ive of something'.

Comment: What will it tell you if I can, @MichaelMunta? Adjectives ending in _-ive_ do not form a natural class. _Attentive_ is used of people, _assertive_ of people or behaviour; _dismissive_ and _argumentative_ usually of people; _imaginative_ and _inventive_ of idease or creations, and people; _suggestive_ of creations but not normally of people, and so on. _Suggestive_ and _dismissive_ usually take "of", _attentive_ takes "to", and several of the other words I mentioned don't normally take a complement phrase like that.